# Why do all PhpMyAdmin browser tabs freeze on long-running queries?

Tags: phpmyadmin

If I execute a long-running query in PhpMyAdmin, I cannot load any other PhpMyAdmin pages in the same browser while the query is still running, even in Chrome which gives each tab its own process (or own thread? I don't remember).

If I open another browser I can log in to PhpMyAdmin, open new pages, and execute more queries while the first browser is still waiting for the long-running query. (If needed this is handy to kill the long-running query under the processes tab.)

Why does it behave like this? Is it something like a cookie session that PhpMyAdmin checks, and then prevents me specifically from executing more queries? Or does PhpMyAdmin use a different protocol (not HTTP) or something weird like that?

(I'm using PhpMyAdmin version 3.3, but I think I saw this behavior with the current version too, a few weeks or a couple months ago.)